# How to fill cell without breaking hyperlink

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am giving automatic hyperlink to cell C1. But it meanwhile user can fill C1. İs it possible?

```
=IF(A1<>"";HYPERLINK("C:\Users\DELL\Downloads"&A1&".bat";C1);"")
```

Comment: In which cell you are putting this formula?

Comment: C1 :D . I know its a bit strange but can it be?

Comment: If  a cell (with formula) is not locked, a user can always overwrite the formula with a value. The formula is then gone.

Comment: So if ı try to put this formula another cell how to copy the just hyperlink to cell C1

Comment: You'd need VBA for this kind of stuff.